# How to specify order validation in Request body Spring Boot Rest Controller

Tags: java, spring-boot, validation, spring-restcontroller, spring-validator

So I have a `Rest Controller` in `Spring Boot` and for an endpoint, I need to validate its `Request Body`.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Validated
@RequestMapping("/my_endpoint")
public class WorkflowController {

    @PostMapping(value = "/blablabla/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Object> createDisconnectRequestRest(@RequestBody List<@CustomValidator @Valid RequestObj> dtos) { // here at the validators is the question
        ... //nevermind
       return null;
    }
```

Request object:

```
@Data
public class RequestObj{

    private String comment;

    @NotNull // this @NotNull annotation validator is triggered AFTER the custom validator is done. I want this to be first validated and then the custom validator should take place
    private List<Long> ids = new ArrayList<>();
}



@Target({FIELD, TYPE_USE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CustomValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ValidRequest {

    String message() default "Invalid request";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

CustomValidator:

```
public class CustomValidator implements ConstraintValidator<ValidRequest, RequestObj> {

 // repositories, constructor 

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(RequestObj request, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintValidatorContext) {
     
         myRepository.findAllById(request.getIds()); // I want the @NotNull annotation validate the object before this custom validator

        return true;
    }
}
```

Here is the **problem**:

The first one to be triggered is the **CustomValidator** and then the `RequestObj` is being validated. In other words, validation starts with the  `@CustomValidator` annotation and then the `@Valid` one. I'd like that the first one to be triggered would be the `@Valid` annotation (so the `@NotNull` annotation would validate the object first) and then the `@CustomValidator` should do its job. For example, if the body field `ids` is NULL, I'd like that the `@CustomValidator` not even start as the validation had already failed.

Comment: Have you tried to change the order of the annotations?

Comment: Yes, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This could be because you have applied `@CustomValidator` annotation at class Level, and classes are loaded first before properties, and that could be the reason you see this order or execution.

You have a few options:

1- Apply this `@CustomValidator` at specific property level,

2- Set your `CustomValidator` as a `@Component`, and remove the `@CustomValidator` annotation from the class level.   Then in your controller method you do:

```
   @Autowired
   private CustomValidator customValidator;

    @PostMapping(value = "/blablabla/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public List<Object> createDisconnectRequestRest(@RequestBody List<@Valid RequestObj> dtos) { // here at the validators is the question
        customValidator.validate(xyz);
    }
```

--- Untested Theory ---

Could you try with changing the order of the annotations applied at the method level and see if it makes a difference:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/blablabla/", consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<Object> createDisconnectRequestRest(@RequestBody List<@Valid @CustomValidator RequestObj> dtos) { // here at the validators is the question
    ... //nevermind
   return null;
}
```

Comment: 1. Adding ```@CustomValidator``` at specific property level is not an option. There I'm validating different kind of property combinations
2. Changing the order doesn't work either.
3. I would like to avoid the workaround where the validation happens inside the controller method

Comment: I found something related to this topic with the ```@GroupSequence``` annotation. I'm reading about it and will update the thread if I find any solution

Comment: `@GroupSequence` is meant to group annotations, in your case, you are looking at priority ordering of *Validators*,so I doubt that it will work.